# If statement after parse query using NsPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, parse-platform, nspredicate

I'm making a parse query using `NSPredicate` to fetch all `objectIds` when either the `senderID` or `receiverID` is my fb id like so:

```
let setPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "senderID = %@ OR receiverID = %@", fbID, fbID)
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Groups", predicate: setPredicate)
    query.addDescendingOrder("updatedAt")
```

I'm then adding the results in an `NSMutableDictionary` and then to an `NSMutableArray` like so:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
        {(objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
                {
                    for object in objects
                    {
                        if setPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "senderID", fbID)
                        self.groupDetailsDict.setValue(object.objectForKey("objectId") as! String, forKey: "groupID")
                        self.groupDetailsDict.setValue(object.objectForKey("senderName"), forKey: "senderName")
                        self.groupDetailsDict.setValue(object.objectForKey("receiverName"), forKey: "receiverName")
                        self.groupDetails.addObject(self.groupDetailsDict)
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
                }
            }
            else
            {
                println(error?.description)
            }
    }
```

I want to add only the `receiverName` if my `fbID` matches the `senderId` and only the `senderName` if my `fbID` matches the `receiverName`. 
Can I use an if else statement inside? if yes, then how?

Comment: What's wrong, explains what doesn't work exactly in your code. In the `for loop`, I don't understand the `if`. You can use a if/else test, but yours seems wrong (`predicateWthformat:`, without placeHolder whereas you put one).

Comment: Nothing is wrong as yet. this code works perfectly to get all values. But the functionality that I want to add I have explained in the question. "I want to add only the receiverName if my fbID matches the senderId and only the senderName if my fbID matches the receiverName. Can I use an if else statement inside? if yes, then how?
"

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your logic comparing ID with ID in first case, and Name with ID in second case, but if we assume that `test` is our target array (sorry, don't quite understand what `groupDetailsDict` mean, maybe you can explain) the code will look something like (with all the proper swift unwrappings):

```
if let senderId = object["senderId"] as? String, receiverName = object["receiverName"] as? String where senderId == fbID {
    test.append(receiverName)
} else if let receiverName = object["receiverName"] as? String, senderName = object["senderName"] as? String where receiverName == fbID {
    test.append(senderName)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. This is a group table for chat. groupDetailsDict is the NSDict where i'm temporarily storing the values fetched from parse and groupDetails is the array where i'm storing NSDictionary objects for further use. so to get all the groups that the client is a part of, I need to get all rows in the table that either have the client as sender (senderID) or receiver(receiverID) that's the first OR logic.

Comment: @AnandAltekar please accept the answer if I helped you.

Comment: Sorry man, that didn't help me. I gave up using parse altogether after this so didn't come across the problem again.